# Fine Tune Model with Caret Package

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using CARET package to fine tune random forest mtry parameter. In the package, tunelength parameter can be used to automate search for best mtry parameter. But the problem is the "tunelength" works when i set minimum 2 folds in crossvalidation. It does not work when i do not want cross validation.

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, number = 2)

set.seed(2)
trained <- train(Y ~ . , data = mydata, method = "rf", ntree = 500, tunelength = 10, metric = "ROC", trControl = ctrl, importance = TRUE)
```

And do anyone know the default setting of tunelength? I mean which value of mtry , it would start with.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't understand what does parameter tuning mean. You want to select the best combination of parameters that improve some quality measure. The thing is that this quality measure can't be computed on the training set itself, because this would lead to over fitting. Crossvalidation precisely gives you an unbiased estimate of your quality measure.

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is the "tunelength" works when i set minimum 2 folds in crossvalidation. It does not work when i do not want cross validation.

I'm not sure what "does not work" means. If you are not resampling, there are not many ways for determining `mtry`. You could use `method = "OOB"` in `trainControl` and use the internal random forest estimate and set `tuneLength` the same way you did before (see these [two](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2014/11/27/vpuig01pqbklmi72b8lcl3ij5hj2qm) [pages](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2014/11/27/08ks7leh0zof45zpf5vqe56d1sahb0) for more details).

Again, I'm not sure if this answers your question.

Max

Comment: Thanks a bunch for developing this awesome package. By "It does not work when i do not want cross validation.", i mean if i want to search for best mtry in my training dataset only with different mtry values, it does not work.

For example, 4 values of mtry - 2,3,4 and 5. It runs RF 4 times with these mtry values and find the mtry value in which AUC is maximum.

Does tunelength for mtry start with (sqrt of variables)?